# Android: BroadcastReceiver() onReceive called when app is suspended

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver() and the onReceive method is called even when the app is suspended/dead. I want the onReceive only to be called when the user opens the notification from the home screen, how can I do that?

MainClass:

```
 broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            }
    };

    final Intent intent = registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

BroadCastReceiver class

```
 Intent intent;
    if(rootActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("myapp"))
    {
        //your app is open
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(rootActivity);

    } else {
        //your app is not open,start it by calling launcher activity
        intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    }

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Manifest

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: Just unregister your receiver when your activity is destroyed.

Comment: Then I do not really understand the question, if you want to be notified only when activity is running then register your receiver when activity starts and unregister it when activity is destroyed.

Comment: If I unregister the receiver then no notifications are received when the app is in "forced stop" state. Is it possible to receive notifications in this situation? I see that the Twitter app does for example...

Comment: Actually no notifications after force stop seems intended behaviour for android, so unregister works!